# how to read a piece of script for ZSH completion?

Tags: zsh, tab-completion

How do I read these lines?

```
#compdef rspec
compadd -P spec/ $(ls spec/**/*_spec.rb | sed -E "s/spec\///g")
```

I understand it's a completion rule for ZSH, but I'm not sure I follow what it is saying....

They come from here, 
https://github.com/thoughtbot/dotfiles/blob/master/zsh/completion/_rspec

Comment: `compadd` is a `zsh` builtin - it does _not_ exist in `bash`.

Comment: Read the documentation of `compadd`: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-compadd Of course there's also `run-help compadd` which includes the same content.

Comment: By the way, I think you should edit the title, which is utterly confusing and doesn't capture your question at all. There's no "piece of bash script" anywhere in your question.

Comment: @mklement0 Oops already deleted... Anyway, I'll leave a link about `run-help` here: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Accessing-On_002dLine-Help (and note that it is not as good as bash's `help` in that it takes you to the appropriate man page from which you need to search).

Comment: To complement @4ae1e1's helpful link: replacing `zsh`'s default `run-help` definition (a mere alias of `man`) with `unalias run-help; autoload -Uz run-help` makes `run-help` support _builtin_ names as operands - you'll get a builtins / completion-related builtins overview page, on which, through in-page searching, you'll find a description of the builtin of interest.

Comment: Why (or how) would you write a zsh completion rule in bash?